# HTML Center my objects on webpage (navbar, image)

Tags: html, css, center

I built this site and I can't get the navbar or my image in the middle. I tried a lot like making flex boxes, setting margins, ... .I just can't find the problem. I hope it isn't a problem that you can't see the pictures etc. because it looks messy.

Here is a part of my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
}

.navBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #9D9C9C;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 95%;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 40%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.voorPagina {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dia architecten</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navBar">
    <img class="logo" src="/Images/LogoDIA.png" />
    <ul>
      <a href="#Projecten">Projecten</a>
      <a href="#Over">Over</a>
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <img class="voorPagina" src="Images/VPDia.png" />

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

You were using `justify-content: space-between;` for the div with `.navBar` class, instead if you go for `justify-content: center;`, it will center all the child elements of the div! Also I added a placeholder image for checking purposes!

**Note:** *Please click on the link `full page` to view the proper centered navbar!*

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
}

.navBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #9D9C9C;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 95%;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 40%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.voorPagina {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dia architecten</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navBar">
    <img class="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/25/" />
    <ul>
      <a href="#Projecten">Projecten</a>
      <a href="#Over">Over</a>
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <img class="voorPagina" src="Images/VPDia.png" />

</body>

</html>
```